# Not allowed to load local resource (windows)

Tags: php, security, filesystems

I am trying to upload some files in local disc C:\ and then read them and display. I have done the following:
at config.php

```
'route'     => 'C:/',
```

the function that gets the path

```
function object_get_upload_path($type,$id){
    $config = app_db_get_config();
    return sprintf($config['route']."uploads/%s/%s/%d/", $_SESSION['active_db'],$type, $id);
}
```

The problem is that when click the link that gets the path of the file and displays it says:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/uploads/MARO_KONDI_AL/objekte/48167/laura1e11c10053fd1c6e5dca911103e5c3ae90072.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to load a file, you have to use the `file_get_contents()` function. Then you should have a look on the server side for the correct synthax.

I suppose the following one would be correct:

```
$config['route'] = 'C:/'; // or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$display = file_get_contents($config['route'].'uploads/'.$_SESSION['active_db'].'/'.$type.'/'.$id);
```